# Adding data to the field having ID in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a collection employees in that I want to put id field along with default _id field. But I can't able to create the record. I tried below way

```
employee = new Employee({id: "1234", name: "emp name"})
employee.save
```

First time it is creating record only with name. Can anyone help me out of this. I put unique index for id field.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose will create an `id` field for you that is returned with `_id` when you save the document, which is why it is overwriting your `id` field you are trying to save it with.

The easiest solution is to call your own id field something else like `uid` or `cid` and that will solve your problem. Particularly as you want to keep the generated `id` field.